# Confusion Matrix

Tags: neural-network, confusion-matrix

### Hi:

I am learning MobileNet in Keras to study NN. But I get confused by the confusion matrix. I do not know why it's so weird. Can any else tell me if this is caused by the matrix code or the other code. Also, please tell me how to solve this.

And here is the code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJUn9.png)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
train_path = './training_set/training_set/'
test_path = './test_set/test_set/'
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(70, 51), batch_size=10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(70, 51), batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
mobile= tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()
x = mobile.layers[-6].output
x_GlobalAveragePooling2D = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x_GlobalAveragePooling2D)
model = Model(inputs = mobile.input, outputs = output)
model.summary()
'''for layer in model.layers[:-23]:
    layer.trainable = False'''
# Train The Model
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=train_batches, epochs=10, verbose=2)
# Predict The Samples
test_labels = test_batches.classes
predictions = model.predict(x = test_batches, verbose=0)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true=test_labels, y_pred=predictions.argmax(axis=1))
test_batches.class_indices
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
            horizontalalignment="center",
            color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
cm_plot_labels = ['cats', 'dogs']
plot_confusion_matrix(cm=cm, classes=cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Matrix')
```

Please anyone can tell me how to out of the situation?

Comment: Using argmax for a single neuron is not correct, you have to threshold the probability at 0.5